# Mysql giving empty result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
  <?php  $bolge="MARMARA";
         $sorgu = "SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE bolge=\"$bolge\"";
         $sonuc=mysql_query($sorgu);
         echo $sorgu;
         $sonuc= mysql_query($sql,$baglanti);
         if(!$sonuc)
         die(mysql_error());
         while($satir= mysql_fetch_array($sonuc))
         {
         $id= $satir["id"];
         $sehir= $satir["sehir"];
         $firma= $satir["firma"];
         $adres= $satir["adres"];
         $tel= $satir["tel"];
         $web= $satir["web"];
        ?>
```

Its my code.

[image: mysql result]

Its my database and connection is done.

Giving this result;

```
SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE bolge="MARMARA";
**Query was empty**
```

Why giving "**Query was empty**" error? I have query and need to give result. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: why you write `mysql_query` 2 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. using mysql_* functions is deprecated
2. use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead
3. try this :

   ```
   $sorgu = "SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE bolge='{$bolge}'";
   ```

However, you may also employ mysql_real_escape_string

Just a question, what is meaning of this :

```
$sonuc=mysql_query($sorgu);  //OK, valid SQL
echo $sorgu;
$sonuc= mysql_query($sql,$baglanti); //Bad, empty (undeclared variable)
```

$sql variable is not set this results in **Query was empty**

Answer (score 2):

try enclosing the value with single quote

```
$sorgu = "SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE bolge='$bolge'";
```

and

```
$sorgu = "SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE bolge='$bolge'";
$sonuc = mysql_query($sorgu);

while ($satir = mysql_fetch_array($sonuc)) 
{
    $id= $satir["id"];
    // other fields.. 
}
```

but your code is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Alternatively, use `PDO` or `MySQLi` extension instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say try to removing (ro at least commenting) this line:

```
$sonuc= mysql_query($sql,$baglanti);
```

It's using undeclared variables `$sql` and `$baglanti`